# How to set a probability of a value becoming a zero for an np.array?

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I've got an np.array 219 by 219 with mostly 0s and 2% of nonzeros and I know want to create new arrays where each of the nonzero values has 90% of chance of becoming a zero.

I now know how to change the n-th non zero value to 0 but how to work with probabilities?

Probably this can be modified:

```
index=0
for x in range(0, 219):
    for y in range(0, 219):
        if (index+1) % 10 == 0:
            B[x][y] = 0
        index+=1
print(B)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and working example of your code.

Comment: B is a matrix 219 by 219 which is simply my data on origin-destination flows between 219 zones in a network. Here I change every 10th nonzero value to a zero, but the more complicated thing to do is that instead of changing every 10th nonzero value to a zero, I have to work with probabilities, i.e. a nonzero value has 90% of probability to become 0.

B can be any 2d array of numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `np.random.random` to create an array of random numbers to compare with 0.9, and then use `np.where` to select either the original value or 0.  Since each draw is independent, it doesn't matter if we replace a 0 with a 0, so we don't need to treat zero and nonzero values differently.  For example:

```
In [184]: A = np.random.randint(0, 2, (8,8))

In [185]: A
Out[185]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])

In [186]: np.where(np.random.random(A.shape) < 0.9, 0, A)
Out[186]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# first method
prob=0.3
print(np.random.choice([2,5], (5,), p=[prob,1-prob]))

# second method (i prefer)    
import random
import numpy as np 
def randomZerosOnes(a,b, N, prob):

    if prob > 1-prob:
        n1=int((1-prob)*N)
        n0=N-n1
    else:
        n0=int(prob*N)
        n1=N-n0  
        
    zo=np.concatenate(([a for _ in range(n0)] ,[b  for _ in range(n1)]  ), axis=0  ) 
    random.shuffle(zo)
    return zo
zo=randomZerosOnes(2,5, N=5, prob=0.3)
print(zo)
```